# How do I move a file in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I have looked everywhere online and I can't seem to find a way to move a file in TCL. Can someone please share the command line that I need to use in order to move the file?

Comment: [`file rename`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M30)

Answer (score 1):

Files can be moved using `file rename` command:

```
file rename -force /path/to/source/file.ext /path/to/dest/
```

`-force` option may be omitted.

See link posted by **glenn jackman** for full reference.

Comment: In particular, this includes moving files between directories and even across filesystems.